# Java-Android | Запустить AsyncTask в потоке или выполнить часть кода через главный поток

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется AsynkTask с GET запросом. В главном потоке всё корректно работает, но...
Всё бы ничего, можно было бы запрос выполнить и в главном, но в основной задаче лежит цикл с множеством запросов и Thread.sleep(). Соответственно не хочется, чтобы вся эта "красота" висела в главном потоке, блокируя доступ к приложению.
Пробовал в Thread классе...

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//Здесь делаю обращение к Asynk, запрос выполняется...
}
});//после этой строки выполнение кода прекращается
```

Задача другими словами:
Имеется класс для запросов.

```
private class GetRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String resultJson = "";
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try {
URL url = new URL("https://sait.ru"+params[0]+params[1]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
buffer.append(line);
}
resultJson = buffer.toString();
JSON = resultJson;
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return resultJson;
}
}
```

То что я сделал:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Users, Integer, Void> {
private Users followers = null;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
followers = UsersMethods.GetFollowers("fields=last_name", new VkToken().GetToken(getApplicationContext()));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Начинаю", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.d("1", "+");
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Users... users) {
Log.d("2", "+");
try {
for (int i = 0; i < followers.Count(); ) {
Thread.sleep(3000);
Log.d("3", "+");
publishProgress(followers.UsersList().get(i).IDProfile());
Log.d("4", "+");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
return null;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... id) {
super.onProgressUpdate(id[0]);
Log.d("5", id[0].toString());
Log.d("6", "+");  new VkApiRequest().Request("friends.add", "user_id=" + id[0].toString(), new VkToken().GetToken(getApplicationContext()));
Log.d("7", "+");
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Готово", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

После `Log.d("6", "+");` ничего не выводится и не происходит из `onProgressUpdate`
Просто в логе начинает выводится

```
3 +
4 +
3 +
4 +
```

Игнорируя `onProgressUpdate`

Буду благодарен любому совету, который выполнит моё пожелание, спасибо!

Comment: Не очень ясна задача, но, возможно, вам нужен `AsyncTask#publishProgress()`

Comment: Всё ещё не совсем понятно в чём вопрос. Вам надо последовательно запустить задачи, а не одновременно?

Comment: HTTP запросы выполняются исключительно не в главном потоке, так? Мне нужно сделать поток с циклом, в котором бы выполнялись  эти запросы

Comment: Ну так поместите цикл внутрь doInBackground и запустите его всего раз....

Comment: Я думал об этом, но мне понадобится множество таких потоков с циклами, и не хотелось бы в каждый поток писать полностью класс запроса.

Comment: Т.е. вам надо типа внутри таска знать кол-во итераций? Можете число через конструктор передать